# Write an xquery that transforms the cdcatalog.xml change the 'country' element to be an attribute on the 'cd' element

Tags: xquery

I am trying to write an xquery statement that transforms the following cdcatalog.xml in order to change the 'country' element to be an attribute on the 'cd' element and add an 'id' attribute to the 'cd' element that is an incremented integer (1,2,3...). Does the FLOWR apply here or I have to use other functions in order add and perform the changes?
The cdcatalog.xml is the following:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
   <title>Hide your heart</title>
   <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
   <country>UK</country>
   <company>CBS Records</company>
   <price>9.90</price>
   <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
   <title>Greatest Hits</title>
   <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
   <country>USA</country>
   <company>RCA</company>
   <price>9.90</price>
   <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
   <title>Still got the blues</title>
   <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
   <country>UK</country>
   <company>Virgin records</company>
   <price>10.20</price>
   <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

And the output should be like this

```
<catalog>
 <cd id="1" country="USA">
   <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
   <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
   <company>Columbia</company>
   <price>10.90</price>
   <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
 <cd id="2" country="UK">
   <title>Hide your heart</title>
   <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
   <company>CBS Records</company>
   <price>9.90</price>
   <year>1988</year>
 </cd>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element catalog {
  for $cd at $pos in doc('cdcatalog.xml')/catalog/cd
  return
    element cd {
      attribute id { $pos },
      attribute country { $cd/country },
      $cd/* except $cd/country
    }
}
```